# Container was not found when looking up a views template

Tags: ember.js

I`m new in Ember and stuck with one problem. I'm trying to build a ContainerView example and cant understand an Error message in my browser

```
Uncaught Error: Container was not found when looking up a views template. 
This is most likely due to manually instantiating an Ember.View. See: 
http://git.io/EKPpnA
```

If i use 1.0.0-rc.1 version of Ember like in this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/dq0yt0tk/
there is no error

If i use 1.7.0 of version of Ember like in this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/yzp6g946/1/
i get an error.

I tried to understand explanation which provided by link, but failed. Please, help

Comment: I found a mistake
the problem was that i used 
 Ember.ContainerView.create instead of  Ember.ContainerView.extend
 Here is the working 
http://jsfiddle.net/yzp6g946/2/

Answer (score 4):

For those, whom the answer below didn't help: In Ember CLI (in conrast to AppKit) you may need to add the following line in the view, where the from comes from.

container: this.container

This solved my problem.

Comment: You saved my day, I've checked lots of answers and this one really solved the issue on Ember CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake
the problem was that i used

```
Ember.ContainerView.create
```

instead of

```
Ember.ContainerView.extend
```

Here is the working http://jsfiddle.net/yzp6g946/2/